# How does Safari calculate size of svg objects?

Tags: safari, svg

How does Safari determine what size to output an svg in the following scenario;

SVG code

```
 viewBox 0 0 800 800
 height 100%
 width 100%
```

css

```
 svg width 100%
 containing div width 60%
```

Safari outputs a much smaller svg than the 60% of screen, ok this is a bug. But what determines the size of this smaller svg, it has no connection to anything I can think of.

Just to give some background info. Safari needs both width and height in px for it to do what you want. % don-t work. But it does output the svg, and so it must make a decision somewhere about its size.

Comment: Just stating the pertinent properties as an example, my code doesn't have much to do with how Safari works...

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug you're seeing. That's the correct behavior. The browser by default scales the SVG *viewbox* (careful with the terminology now, we're not talking about the browser *viewport*) to fill the CSS-determined dimensions of the SVG element. The fill behavior is determined by the SVG [preserveAspectRatio](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) attribute. By default it's set to `meet`, which keeps the whole SVG viewable, and the aspect ratio preserved. The alternative is `slice` which scales the viewbox up to cover the element, even when that means cropping. (`slice` behaves similarly to `background-size:cover` in CSS3.)

What you need to do is:

a) Don't declare explicit height or width in the SVG file. If your graphics editor is generating them, just go in by hand and delete them. According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#SVGElementWidthAttribute), if no width and height are specified, a value of 100% is assumed, so your pseudocode is redundant at best.

b) Make sure you're setting an explicit height for the svg element in CSS. I recommend developer or Canary builds of Chrome for troubleshooting responsive svg sizing, as there is a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118996) in Chrome 18 Dev Tools that has since been fixed. Once you've got it working in Chrome, it will almost certainly also work in Safari.

c) Figure out how you want to set preserveAspectRatio and manually edit the svg to put in the declaration.

If you're still having trouble, please post a jsfiddle. It's much easier for other people to  comment on.

Comment: Delete width and hight attribute from the <svg> tag, is a good solution. Thanks.